# Initialize Orion with persistent data

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I am developing a simple project in orion to subscribe to the context change of some entities. I would like to initialize the orion service with data when I instantiate the container in docker with a list of data.
This is the docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  # Orion-LD Context Broker
  orion:
    container_name: fiware-orion
    image: fiware/orion:latest
    hostname: orion
    depends_on:
      - mongo-db
    expose:
      - "1026"
    ports:
      - "1026:1026"
    volumes:
      - ./data/orion:/usr/local/bin
    command: -dbhost mongo-db -logLevel DEBUG
    networks:
      - default
  
  # Database
  mongo-db:
    container_name: fiware-mongo
    image: mongo:4.4
    hostname: mongo-db
    expose:
      - "27017"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    command: --nojournal
    volumes:
      - ./data/mongo-db:/data
    networks:
      - default

networks:
  default:
```

This is the data I would like to insert (I wrote it in bash):

```
# Add devices
curl -s -o /dev/null -X POST 'http://orion:1026/v2/op/update'\
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json'\
    -g -d '{
        "actionType": "append",
        "entities": [
            {
                "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Device:9845A",
                "type": "Device",
                "deviceCategory": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": [
                        "sensor"
                    ]
                },
                "controlledAsset": {
                    "type": "Relationship",
                    "value": [
                        "urn:ngsi-ld:Building:2"
                    ]
                },
                "controlledProperty": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": [
                        "temperature",
                        "humidity"
                    ]
                },
                "batteryLevel": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": {
                        "@type": "Number",
                        "@value": 0.75
                    }
                },
                "value": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": "t%3D0.22%3Bh%3D58.3"
                },
                "dateFirstUsed": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": {
                        "@type": "DateTime",
                        "@value": "2023-03-23T11:00:00Z"
                    }
                },
                "deviceState": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": "ok"
                },
                "direction": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": "Inlet"
                },
                "serialNumber": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": "9845A"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Device:1284P",
                "type": "Device",
                "deviceCategory": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": [
                        "sensor"
                    ]
                },
                "controlledAsset": {
                    "type": "Relationship",
                    "value": [
                        "urn:ngsi-ld:Building:4"
                    ]
                },
                "controlledProperty": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": [
                        "occupancy"
                    ]
                },
                "batteryLevel": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": {
                        "@type": "Number",
                        "@value": 0.92
                    }
                },
                "value": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": "43"
                },
                "dateFirstUsed": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": {
                        "@type": "DateTime",
                        "@value": "2023-03-23T11:00:00Z"
                    }
                },
                "deviceState": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": "ok"
                },
                "direction": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": "Inlet"
                },
                "serialNumber": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": "1284P"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Device:5726B",
                "type": "Device",
                "deviceCategory": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": [
                        "sensor"
                    ]
                },
                "controlledAsset": {
                    "type": "Relationship",
                    "value": [
                        "urn:ngsi-ld:Building:5"
                    ]
                },
                "controlledProperty": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": [
                        "precipitation"
                    ]
                },
                "batteryLevel": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": {
                        "@type": "Number",
                        "@value": 0.45
                    }
                },
                "value": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": "26.14"
                },
                "dateFirstUsed": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": {
                        "@type": "DateTime",
                        "@value": "2023-03-23T11:00:00Z"
                    }
                },
                "deviceState": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": "ok"
                },
                "direction": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": "Outlet"
                },
                "serialNumber": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": "5726B"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Device:4858R",
                "type": "Device",
                "deviceCategory": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": [
                        "sensor"
                    ]
                },
                "controlledAsset": {
                    "type": "Relationship",
                    "value": [
                        "urn:ngsi-ld:OnStreetParking:1"
                    ]
                },
                "controlledProperty": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": [
                        "occupancy"
                    ]
                },
                "batteryLevel": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": {
                        "@type": "Number",
                        "@value": 0.84
                    }
                },
                "value": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": "12"
                },
                "dateFirstUsed": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": {
                        "@type": "DateTime",
                        "@value": "2023-03-23T11:00:00Z"
                    }
                },
                "deviceState": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": "ok"
                },
                "direction": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": "Entry"
                },
                "serialNumber": {
                    "type": "Property",
                    "value": "4858R"
                }
            }
        ]
    }'
```

I tried with `command: sh -c “ -dbhost mongo-db -logLevel && import-data.sh”` but it say me that command `sh` is not valid.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

Specifically for the **Orion Context Broker**, the backing database is **Mongo-DB**. Whereas the dockerization of the broker doesn't pre-support a *"load this persisted data"* option, Mongo-DB already does, and this is well documented.

You should firstly load the necessary data into Orion, and then take a dump the mongo-database:

```bash
docker exec db-mongo sh -c 'mongodump --archive' > backups/db.dump
```

The Mongo DB dockerization accepts a  `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE` environment variable to run a bash script on start up, so in addition to the data dump, you'll need a script to restore the database, For example create a file called `mongoRestore/mongoRestore.sh`. Add the following code:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
exec mongorestore --archive < backups/db.dump
```

The `mongo-db` element in the `docker-compose` file will need three new elements - a reference to the script and two files loaded as volumes as shown

Add to `mongo-db:`

```yaml
environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongoRestore.sh
volumes:
      - ../backups/db.dump:/backups/db.dump
      - ../mongoRestore/mongoRestore.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongoRestore.sh
```

This code makes sure that the database is restored when it is started.
More details can be found [here](https://github.com/MarvynBornemann/tutorials.IoT-Agent/blob/NGSI-LD/mongoRestore/mongoRestore.md)

#### Option 2

It may be the case that you want to use the NGSI interface to upsert data directly rather than relying on a data dump. In this case you can use a dockerization of cUrl to insert the data as shown

```bash
docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/import-data:/import-data.sh \
    --network <network-name> \
    --entrypoint /bin/ash curlimages/curl
```

`-network` refers to the network set up by docker-compose, for example if have set `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=fiware` and the `docker-compose.yml` uses `network:default` this will be `fiware-default`. The script `import-data.sh` loaded as a volume would have the NGSI upsert statements within in. This is the mechanism currently used by the FIWARE tutorials.

Comment: Sorry but I'm new with dockerization. Would it be possible to modify my docker-compose so that orion-ld when it is created directly imports the entities from the .sh files I have defined? I have tried entering an `-entrypoint: sh -c import-data.sh` but it says this command is not supported.

Comment: The problem with using a new `entrypoint` is that  what you actually want is Orion to start up, wait until it is ready to receive input, then send the update, and finally terminate-and-stay-resident whilst watching the output log. To get the timing right on that using a bash script would be very tricky.  

It is better to leave the Orion initialization alone and cover  your needs from a second container.

Comment: Of course you could try [raising an issue](https://github.com/FIWARE/context.Orion-LD/issues) over on GitHub to see if Orion could support a `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE` style initialisation parameter. In other words automatically run a user-defined bash-script once  the start-up sequence has completed.